# Randomly generating an int value in for loop. After 7 iterations, it returns a very large negative number. Why is this?

Tags: c#, wpf, for-loop, random

The code below is rotating a wheel either 10 times or 1 time depending on whether or not the user selects 'yes'.

The rotation method takes a number between 0-100, and rotates the filter an amount based on that number. To test the machine, I want to generate a random number between 0-99. I feel this method should be able to do that. However, after 7 times, the random number produced is -2.147483465E+09 until the end of the run. The output, for example:

```
 89
 20
 1
 58
 78
 39
 90
 -2.147483465E+09
 -2.147483465E+09
 -2.147483465E+09
```

Could this be something related to garbage collection? The 'sUVFilter' is not changed to 0 by the method, these are the values it gets when I set it = to rand.Next();

Any help or information would be appreciated! Thanks a lot. Here is the code in question.

```
    private void RotateFilterWheel()
    {
        List<float> filterValuesList = new List<float>();
        int timesToRotate = 1;
        int success = 0;
        Random rand = new Random();

        MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("Rotate filter 10 times?", "Rotate Filter", MessageBoxButton.YesNo);
        if (result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
        {
            timesToRotate = 10;
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < timesToRotate; x++)
        {

            int sUVFilter = rand.Next(99);
            _instDrvr.SetSpectroAutoUVFilterPosition(sUVFilter, ref success);
            filterValuesList.Add(sUVFilter);
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }
        listBox.ItemsSource = filterValuesList;
    }
```

From the comments:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Post a minimal, complete, verifiable example.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I understand, my apologies. I thought you were asking why I was stopping it for 50 seconds each time.

Here is a screen-shot of this occurring with a watch on sUVFilter, just after it's been set by the rand.Next(99) line and before _instDrvr has touched it.

http://imgur.com/YFNYpfH

It's not the listbox. The values occur as sUVFilter gets set.

Comment: @RobAdams, what is `_instDrvr`?

Answer (score 2):

```
    _instDrvr.SetSpectroAutoUVFilterPosition(sUVFilter, ref success);
```

That is the real trouble-maker in your program.  We don't know enough about it, other than it appears to operate a motor.  So you are probably use some company's library to do this, such code is often unmanaged.  Could be a COM component, could be using pinvoke.

The diagnostic is that it corrupts the stack of your method.  There is more than one way it could do this.  One easy way is that it corrupts the value of the EBP processor register in 32-bit code, the RSP register in 64-bit code.  Easy to check, use Debug > Windows > Registers and double-check that the register has the exact same value before and after the call.

And it can corrupt the stack frame easily, especially so thanks to the `ref success` argument.  Which passes a pointer to your success variable, stored on the stack frame.  Gives it way to easily write more than 4 bytes, this will cause other local variable(s) of your method to randomly change their value.  Such memory corruption is much harder to diagnose, other than the obviously weirdo values you see back in the debugger.

That's about all that can be guessed at, you almost certainly need help from the motor controller manufacturer or software vendor to get this problem solved.